# Is it mandatory to put inner try-with-resources or everything inside one of the try-with-resources will be autoclosed?

Tags: java, datasource, try-with-resources

Is it mandatory to put inner try-with-resources or everything inside one of the try-with-resources will be autoclosed?

```
    try (BasicDataSource ds = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(dsProperties)) {

        // still necessary for Connection to close if inside
        // try-with-resources?
        try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString("email"));
                        System.out.println(rs.getString("password"));
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: why you are using many `try-with-resources`, use only one and put multiple statements using `;`. And it will take care of closing all.

Comment: thank you @jack jay, that was exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a try-with-resources block, **only the resources in the `try` statement will be closed automatically** by the try-with-resources construct. Other resources within the block are unrelated, and must be managed<sup>(*)</sup>.

However, you can put multiple resources in the `try` statement,
instead of using multiple try-with-resources (one for each resource) for example:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("email"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("password"));
    }
}
```

<sup>(*)</sup>As [@alexander-farber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165071/alexander-farber) pointed out in a comment, there are also some resources that get closed automatically by other mechanism, for example a `ResultSet` gets closed when the `Statement` that generated it gets closed. Although you don't manage those resources explicitly, they are managed by their implementation.

Comment: Your statement "Only the resources in the try statement will be closed automatically" is wrong, because  [A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber good point. This question is about the try-with-resources mechanism. You're right that `ResultSet` gets closed when the `Statement` gets closed, but this is not because of the try-with-resources. I clarified my answer, thanks for pointing this out.